# the meaning of 'inked out to black'

Tags: phrase-meaning

> When the woodcock flew up in its flash of reddish brown, his heart had
>   knocked hard. As they rode he was aware of it, each beat a heavy
>   wing-beat; as the bird found the concealment of trees, its tracing of
>   feathers **inked out to black**.
>
> Bring Up the Bodies by Hilary Mantel

What does '**inked out to black**' mean?

Comment: I understand it thus: The outline of its feathers blended into the dark background. It might well be time for computer word processors to have an anti-pretentious filter! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ink out a word is to write or scribble over it with the nib of the pen until it becomes illegible.

> The author of these handwritten missives has inked out a word which can
>   only be guessed at from the descenders and ascenders that remain
>   visible.

Thus "its tracing of feathers inked out to black" would  mean "its tracing of feathers having become indistinguishable (like letters which had been inked out)".